# .htaccess redirect if # exist in URI

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

i've been looking for this solution and i couldnt find anything.

the idea is redirect  depend on URI string but the problem is htaccess can't catch **#**.

**IF** **#** exist in *URI*  redirect to **LINK_A**

**ELSE** redirect to **LINK_B**

here my little code and its not working for me

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^((?!#).)*$ http://google.fr [L,R=301,NE]
RewriteRule # http://redirect.fr [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule #(.+)$ /? [L,R=301,NE]` or `RewriteRule \x23.+$ / [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#` in URL is fragment identifier and is not passed to the server.

[Fragment_identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

> The fragment identifier functions differently to the rest of the URI:
>   its processing is exclusively client-side with no participation from
>   the web server, though the server typically helps to determine the
>   MIME type, and the MIME type determines the processing of fragments.
>   When an agent (such as a Web browser) requests a web resource from a
>   Web server, the agent sends the URI to the server, but does not send
>   the fragment. Instead, the agent waits for the server to send the
>   resource, and then the agent processes the resource according to the
>   document type and fragment value.

Comment: there is no solution exist ?

Comment: As I know there is no solution for that. If this is your front end then you may url encode `#` in the path. But if this is an external server - is not going outside browser,

Comment: yes its my side work but i have no idea how to do it

Comment: Please attach your frontend code, that is responsible for sending that URLs and I try to help.